# How to split a string into 2 strings using RegEx?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need a regEx to retrieve the street of a string and the streetnumber. Let's consider that the streetname starts from the beginning until there is a whitespace followed by a number

example:

Original string: 'Jan van Rijswijcklaan 123'
Result should be: 'Jan van Rijswijcklaan' as the streetname and '123' as the streetnumber.

any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I was able to get the streetname and number, but sometimes I had streetnumbers like '123b a1' then the code failed in defining the streetnumber. As result for the streetnumber was only 'a1' instead of '123b a1'.

So at the moment I'm dealing with 2 scenarios:

1. When streetname contains only alphabetic characters and number contains only digits - like 'Jan van Rijswijcklaan 123'
2. When streetname contains only alphabetic characters and number contains alphanumeric characters - like 'Jan van Rijswijcklaan 123b a1'

Here is the code I tried:

```
string street = Regex.Match(streetWithNum, @"^[^0-9]*").Value + ";";
string number = Regex.Match(streetWithNum, @"\w\d*\w?\d*$").Value + ";";
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried including a complete code sample and what is not working.

Comment: I think this is very hard to do with a regex. Because those dutch names in the street have spaces. And checking only on a single space wont do the trick. Isn't it better to have 2 single fields one for the Street and one of the Number

Comment: So you don't have a `11 september straat` in Holland?

Comment: How about `Fort 7-straat 77`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use positive lookahead pattern to search spliting condition:

```
var s = "Jan van Rijswijcklaan 124";
var result = Regex.Split(s, @"\s(?=\d)");

Console.WriteLine("street name: {0}", result[0]);
Console.WriteLine("street number: {0}", result[1]);
```

prints:

```
street name: Jan van Rijswijcklaan
street number: 124
```

note: use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) to convert street number from string to int, if you need to

Comment: nice solution but how about a streetname with a number in it?

Comment: @JordyvanEijk from OP questions: `Let's consider that the streetname starts from the beginning until there is a whitespace followed by a number`.

Comment: Shouldn't the street number be 124 rather than 24? (might want to use a lookahead so the number doesn't get chopped in the split match)

Comment: @Ilya Ivanov: I understand your idea but there can be streetnames with numbers in it with a Whitespace.
I Saw someone writing `Helmerstraat 1e 14 or Helmerstraat 1 14` instead of `1e Helmerstraat 14`

Comment: Your lookahead matches the first digit in input so "Helmerstraat 1e 14" still gets split into "Helmerstraat" and "1e 14".

Comment: Yeah i know but that is the problem. It should be  streetname `Helmerstraat 1e` and housnumber `14`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of regex, do you notice that?

```
IEnumerable<string> nameParts = "Jan van Rijswijcklaan 124".Split()
    .TakeWhile(word => !word.All(Char.IsDigit));
string name = string.Join(" ", nameParts);
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/QQU4ff)</kbd>

If you want to take both, the street-name and the number:

```
string[] words = "Jan van Rijswijcklaan 124".Split();
var streetNamePart = words.TakeWhile(w => !w.All(Char.IsDigit));
var streetNumberPart = words.SkipWhile(w => !w.All(Char.IsDigit));
Console.WriteLine("street-name: {0}", string.Join(" ", streetNamePart));
Console.WriteLine("street-number: {0}", string.Join(" ", streetNumberPart));
```

Comment: Tim, while I'm also not a big fan of regular expressions and a big fan of LINQ, is the usage of LINQ justified here? I'm not speaking about performance, but more about readability and maintainability. Don't get me wrong, there are lots of cases where regexs are overused, but I just doubt a bit about this situation.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: It's a matter of taste. In my opinion it is justified if it works without regex. Isn't this readable: `word.All(Char.IsDigit)` if you want to know if a word contains only digits?

Comment: Not an answer, the original poster asked for a regex.

Comment: Yes, sure. But anyone who knows regular expression should find `\s\d` very easy to understand. Spliting by space followed by a digit. Moreover if you change criteria (spaces and tabs, for example. Or Number and slashes) regular is super easy to adapt in this scenario. The power of DSL sometimes being very short and useful. Tim, please don't get insulted, with all respect I'm just curious, do you validate emails, for example, without regulars? It surely can be done using linq manipulations

Comment: @ifdefdebug: It is an answer and it might also be helpful (even for OP). If OP has to use regex he can accept a different answer.

Comment: @Tim: I agree it might be helpful. I do not agree that this is an answer to "How to split a string into 2 strings using RegEx?"

Answer (score 0):

Here a non-regex solution also;

```
string str = "Jan van Rijswijcklaan 124";
var array = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string streetname = "";
string streetnumber = "";
foreach (var item in array)
{
     if (Char.IsNumber(item[0]))
         streetnumber += item;
      else
         streetname += item + " ";
}

Console.WriteLine(streetname.TrimEnd());
Console.WriteLine(streetnumber);
```

Output will be;

```
Jan van Rijswijcklaan
124
```

Here a <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/3Gu9Mh)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Than just fix the answer of @Ilya_Ivanov with lookahead:

```
var result = Regex.Split(s, @"\s(?=\d)");
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(.+?) (\d+)$");
Match m = r.Match("Jan van Rijswijcklaan 124");
String street = m.Groups[1].Value;
String number = m.Groups[2].Value;
```

I typed this from memory, don't blame me for typos :)

edit: the '$' at the end of the regex string makes sure the number match to occur only at the end of the input string.

edit 2: just removed the typos and tested the code, it works now.

edit 3: the expression can be read as: Collect as many characters as you can get into group 1 without being greedy (.+?) but leave a sequence of digits at the end of the string, after a whitespace, for group 2 (\d+)$